# arrayHistogram implementation

Tags: java, programming-challenge, array

I wrote this code, called `arrayHistogram`, that would generate a random number within a set range, and print it in an array `randomIntArray`. It would then make another array `arrayHist` that would count how many times each number in `randomIntArray` occurred. The program works, but, I feel I have a few semantic errors in the syntax, that's not printing `arrayHist` correctly. I would like to review it and see where the errors are so I can correct them. Also, If you feel like you can offer me a more efficient methods, and means for this code, feel free to do so, I'll take it into consideration.

```
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
                int[] array=randomIntArray(30);//declares the dimensions of the array     "randomIntArray"
                System.out.println("Scores:");
                printArray(array);//calls the scoreHist method to print the "array variable
                System.out.println("\n"+"count: ");
                printArray(arrayHist(array));//calls score hist, to call arrayHist, to count "array"
                System.out.println();
    }

        public static int randomInt(int low, int high){//the prng
                double e;
                double x=Math.random();
                    e=low+x*(high-low);
                return (int)e;}

        public static int[] randomIntArray(int n){//generates an array of random numbers based on an upper and lower bound
                int[] a=new int[n];
                for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
                    {a[i]=randomInt(-5,15);}//"-5&15 are the lower and upper bounds of the random number array
                return a;}

        public static int inRange(int[] a, int low, int high){//checks if the numbers of the random number array are in certain constraints.
                int count=0;
                for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
                    {if(a[i]>=low&&a[i]<=high)count++;}
                return count;}

        public static int[] arrayHist(int[] scores){//counts how many of each number occurs in "randomIntArray"
                int[] counts=new int[11];
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                    {counts[i]=inRange(scores,i,i++);}
                return counts;}

        public static void printArray(int[] a){//prints any array, with only one traversal.
                for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
                    {System.out.print(" "+a[i]);}
            }
}
```

My goal is to not use any of the array methods Java provides (to challenge myself), so please don't offer them up.

Comment: Look at this: http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text. Then look at your code.

Comment: Ah, I see now. How can I avoid this int the future, as, I am knew to stackExchange

Comment: Do what Lyle suggested and add more spaces between the lines in your code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add some spaces in between operators and format the code properly

all I did here was

- added spaces between operators
- moved the curly braces to their appropriate locations for Egyptian Style Bracing
- set indentation to standard, you had some lines that were indented and they shouldn't have been

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = randomIntArray(30); //declares the dimensions of the array "randomIntArray"
    System.out.println("Scores:");
    printArray(array); //calls the scoreHist method to print the "array variable
    System.out.println("\n" + "count: ");
    printArray(arrayHist(array)); //calls score hist, to call arrayHist, to count "array"
    System.out.println();
}
public static int randomInt(int low, int high) { //the prng
    double e;
    double x=Math.random();
    e=low+x*(high-low);
    return (int)e;
}
public static int[] randomIntArray(int n) { //generates an array of random numbers based on an upper and lower bound
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = randomInt(-5, 15);
    } //"-5&15 are the lower and upper bounds of the random number array
    return a;
}
public static int inRange(int[] a, int low, int high) { //checks if the numbers of the random number array are in certain constraints.
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] >= low && a[i] <= high) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
public static int[] arrayHist(int[] scores) { //counts how many of each number occurs in "randomIntArray"
    int[] counts=new int[11];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        counts[i] = inRange(scores, i, i++);
    }
    return counts;
}
public static void printArray(int[] a) { //prints any array, with only one traversal.
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + a[i]);
    }
}
```

---

I noticed that you are using a For loop, and I think that you should be using more foreach loops.  I am going to use this code as an example

> ```
> public static int inRange(int[] a, int low, int high) { //checks if the numbers of the random number array are in certain constraints.
>     int count = 0;
>     for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
>         if(a[i] >= low && a[i] <= high) count++;
>     }
>     return count;
> }
> ```

so what you get is now this

```
public static int inRange(int[] a, int low, int high) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i : a) {
        if(i >= low && i <= high) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

which is slightly cleaner than the OP.

I also removed the comments on this method, mainly because they were unnecessary. you have a lot of comments in this code some of which are not needed at all, probably all of them.  most of your variables are named appropriately so you don't have a doubt what they stand for.  nothing is too complex here that you would need to explain what is going on.

<s>here are the comments I would get rid of</s>

- //declares the dimensions of the array "randomIntArray"
- //declares the dimensions of the array "randomIntArray"
- //the prng

Here is the only comment that I would keep

```
//counts how many of each number occurs in "randomIntArray"
```

on the ArrayHist Method. because the Method name doesn't really tell me that right away.

---

All Methods should be named in PascalCase, variables in camelCase.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, that arrayHist method does what it's intended to do.

```
public static int[] arrayHist(int[] scores)//counts how many of each number occurs in "randomIntArray"
{
    int[] counts = new int[11];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        counts[i] = inRange(scores, i, i++);
    }
    return counts;
}
```

What worries me here, is that you increment counter `i` inside `for` loop body. ***Even if it was intended, I still suggest you to avoid this technique, because it complicates understanding of logic.***
Also, I dared to rewrite this method, so that it builds histogram correctly (according to my understanding of course).

```
//counts how many of each number occurs in "randomIntArray"
public static int[] arrayHist(int[] scores)
{
    int[] counts = new int[NUMBER_OF_POSSIBLE_VALUES];
    for (int score : scores) {
        counts[score - LOWER_BOUND]++;
    }
    return counts;
}
```

***I moved `-5` and `15` out of `randomIntArray` function, and suggest you to do the same.*** Now they are constants called `LOWER_BOUND` and `UPPER_BOUND` respectively. I also initialize constant called `NUMBER_OF_POSSIBLE_VALUES` that is equal to

```
Math.abs(LOWER_BOUND) + (Math.abs(UPPER_BOUND)-1) + 1;
```

I decrement `UPPER_BOUND` modulus, because it's exclusive in `randomInt`; and add 1 to count zero.
Ok, back to `arrayHist` method. Now it initializes `counts` as array of zeros with size equal to number of every possible value that could be in your random int array. Now you should think that indexation of `count` starts not from 0 (zero), but from lower bound of range. After loop you get number of occurrences for those possible values from your range.
*Surely, this code works nice as far as you don't change bounding values. If you will make them too big, it could cause overflow or OOM during `counts` allocation (in which case, you would probably want to switch from array to something like map).*